# Is there any rule that prohibits a character from using Wish to cast Simulacrum on a hostile humanoid?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, wish, simulacrum

Could a character use  *Wish* to cast *Simulacrum* (thus requiring only one action and no material components) on any humanoid target?

Comment: Is this the feature of wish that you are trying to exploit?  *The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower. You don't need to meet any requirements in that spell, including costly components. The spell simply takes effect*  If so, please fold that into the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you could make a Simulacrum of another creature, even an unwilling one. The spell doesn't require a willing target, saving throw or spell attack. Merely that the target is within touch-range for the casting.

You don't even need Wish for this; if you can somehow keep a creature in place for 12 hours you can already make a duplicate of an unwilling target. (For example because they are sleeping, knocked out, imprisoned, or in a coma)

Wish just makes it a *lot* easier because the casting time is so short. But nothing in the Simulacrum spell prevents its use on hostile targets. You'll end up with a duplicate of your enemy except they're friendly to you and have half of their hit points.

(Keep in mind the spell does not say it also knows everything the original knows. If this was a plan to steal a secret from them, it might not work.)

Comment: That's exactly it. It's an expensive doppelganger, of course, but it might be useful. Thanks!